# How to test Dialogs in Cucumber?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, dialog, cucumber, capybara

I am using jquery UI dialogs in Rails.

How do you use cucumber to test for opening dialogs? I have a registration dialog and after that another confirmation dialog. The latter appearing after successful signup.

However I noticed that when cucumber presses sign up button to submit, it never really tests for the other pop up dialog. And if I disabled the opening of the 2nd dialog, cucumber still passes. It seems the modal is invisible but it can be seen by cucumber. Has anyone encountered this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introduce wrapper step - it will basically evaluate step with scoping it to dialog container.

```
 Then /^(.*) within the dialog$/ do |wrapped_step, selector_text|
   with_scope(".jquery-ui-dialog-class") do
     Then wrapped_step
   end
 end
```

After that you'll be able to add steps like

```
 Then I should see "Confirmation text" within the dialog
 When I press "Ok" within the dialog
```

P.S: Don't forget to put correct class into the step, I forget which one is used in jQuery UI but I believe that it should be something like ".dialog"

Comment: but I am already using scopes, like I should see something within something, but the problem is that it sees the dialog even though I haven't opened it yet..so I can't make it fail

Comment: 2 ways of doing it that quickly came into my mind 1. Check css visible property (Add custom step for that). 2. Use selenium - it forbids interacting with invisible elements.